# Find the values in ValidateSet

Tags: powershell

I was wondering if there was a way to retrieve the values used in the clause `Param()` for `ValidateSet`. Something like this would be great:

```
Function Foo {
    Param (
        [ValidateSet('Startup', 'Shutdown', 'LogOn', 'LogOff')]
        [String]$Type = 'Startup'
    )

    $Type.ValidateSet
}
```

But of course there is no such property on the `Type` object. Is it possible to retrieve the values set in `ValidateSet`?

Comment: What about using `Get-Command Foo | Select -Expand Definition` to extract the validate set from the resulting string?

Comment: The thing is I use the `Param()` clause at the top of my script. so that would be difficult. I need to be able to find it in the script itself if it is at all possible. But thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
function Foo {
    param (
        [ValidateSet('Startup', 'Shutdown', 'LogOn', 'LogOff')]
        [String]$Type = 'Startup'
    )

    $ParameterList = (Get-Command -Name $MyInvocation.MyCommand).Parameters
    $ParameterList["Type"].Attributes.ValidValues
}
```

After your comment:

```
param (
        [ValidateSet('Startup', 'Shutdown', 'LogOn', 'LogOff')]
        [String]$Type = 'Startup'
)


(Get-Variable "Type").Attributes.ValidValues
```

The `Get-Variable` call also works in a function.

Comment: Works perfectly! Except when I do a `Set-Location` to a network folder before I run the code. Really weird...

Comment: @DarkLite1: works for me ... (PowerShell 5 on Windows 10)

Comment: Correct, the first time I run the code it works fine. When I run it a second time in the ISE it's not generating any output. Really strange... Win 7 PS 4.0.

Comment: Nicely done, but the `Get-Command -Name` part is both unnecessary and brittle. Omitting it makes the first snippet work in both functions and scripts, except if `Set-StrictMode` is set to `-version 2` or higher.
It's implied by your last sentence, but just to state it explicitly: The simpler `Get-Variable` approach works in both scripts and functions as well (but the `Set-StrictMode` caveat applies).

Comment: Thx for the great feedback! Indeed, opened a new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42712595/why-does-get-variable-only-works-the-first-time) for this.

Answer (score 6):

All solutions below work in *both* functions *and* scripts.

**Most robust solution** that should work in any invocation scenario, **PSv2+**:

```
param (
    [ValidateSet('Startup', 'Shutdown', 'LogOn', 'LogOff')]
    [String]$Type = 'Startup'
)

# -> @('Startup', 'Shutdown', ...)
($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Parameters['Type'].Attributes |
  Where-Object { $_ -is [ValidateSet] }).ValidValues
```

A **simpler, but potentially fragile PSv3+** solution, which **assumes**:

- that `Set-StrictMode` is either set to `-Version 1` or not set.

  - **`Set-StrictMode` may have been set outside of your control**, so if you don't fully control the execution environment, it is safer to use the more verbose, PSv2-compatible command above.
    <sup>(The `Set-StrictMode` setting behaves like a variable: it is *inherited* by descendent scopes, but setting it in a descendent scope sets it *locally* (only affects *that* scope and *its* descendants).)</sup>
  - However:

    - You can explicitly run `Set-StrictMode -Off` or `Set-StrictMode -Version 1` *at the start of your script / function*, though you may want to restore the desired value afterwards. Whatever mode you set will affect descendant scopes too. Note that that there is *no* way to *query* the strict mode currently in effect.
    - If you define a function as part of a [*module*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878324(v=vs.85).aspx), the outside world's `Set-StrictMode` setting does *not* apply.
- that running into [this bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42724896/45375) (still present as of PowerShell 7.3.1) when repeatedly *dot-sourcing* a script is not a concern.

```
param (
    [ValidateSet('Startup', 'Shutdown', 'LogOn', 'LogOff')]
    [String]$Type = 'Startup'
)

# Assumes that at most Set-StrictMode -Version 1 is in effect.
# You could explicitly run Set-StrictMode -Off or Set-StrictVersion -Version 1 
# in here first.
(Get-Variable Type).Attributes.ValidValues
```

---

#### Optional background information

The PSv3+ shorthand syntax `(Get-Variable Type).Attributes.ValidValues` is essentially the equivalent of:

```
(Get-Variable Type).Attributes | ForEach-Object { $_.ValidValues }
```

That is, PowerShell automatically enumerates the *collection* `.Attributes` and collects the values of *each element's* `.ValidValues` property.

In the case at hand, only *one* attribute in the `.Attributes` collection - the one of subtype `[System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute]` -  has a `.ValidValues` property, so that single value is returned.

Given that the other attributes have no such property, setting [`Set-StrictMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode) to `-version 2` or higher causes the attempt to access a nonexistent property to raise an error, and the command *fails*.

```
((Get-Variable Type).Attributes |
  Where-Object { $_ -is [System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute] }).ValidValues
```

bypasses this problem by explicitly targeting the one attribute of interest (using the `-is` operator to identify it by type) that is known to have a `.ValidValues` property.

The more verbose alternative to accessing the attributes of parameter [variable] `$Type` with `(Get-Variable Type).Attributes` is to use `$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Parameters['Type'].Attributes`.

Use of the `$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Parameters` collection enables enumerating and inspecting *all* parameters without needing to know their names in advance.

---

[David Brabant's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42697469/45375) is helpful, but (as of this writing):

- It may create the mistaken impression that separate approaches are needed for scripts and functions.
- The `Get-Command -Name $MyInvocation.MyCommand` part is:

  - *unnecessary*, because `$MyInvocation.MyCommand` *itself* provides the information of interest:
    `$MyInvocation.MyCommand` is an instance of type `[System.Management.Automation.ExternalScriptInfo]` in *scripts*, and type `[System.Management.Automation.FunctionInfo]` in *functions*, both of which derive from type `[System.Management.Automation.CommandInfo]`, which is the type that `Get-Commmand` returns - so not only do they provide the same information, they also *unambiguously* refer to the enclosing script/function.
  - *brittle*:

    - `$MyInvocation.MyCommand` is converted to a *string* due to being passed to the `-Name` parameter, which in a *script* results in the script's *mere filename* (e.g., `script.ps1`), and in a *function* in the function's *name* (e.g., `Foo`).
    - In a *script*, this will *typically* cause `Get-Command` not to find the script at all - unless that script happens to be in the PATH (one of the directories listed in `$env:PATH`). But that also means that a *different* script that happens to have the same filename and that happens to be / come first in the PATH may be matched, yielding incorrect results.
      In short: `Get-Command -Name $MyInvocation.MyCommand` in scripts will often *break*, and when it does return a result, it may be for the wrong script.
    - In a *function*, it can identify the wrong command too, although that is much less likely:
      Due to [PowerShell's command precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/about/about_Command_Precedence), a given name is first interpreted as an *alias*, and then as a *function*, so, in theory, with a `Foo` *alias* defined, `Get-Command -Name $MyInvocation.MyCommand` inside *function* `Foo` would mistakenly return information about the *alias*.
      (It's nontrivial to *invoke* function `Foo` while alias `Foo` is defined, but it can be done; e.g.: `& (Get-Item Function:Foo)`)

Answer (score 0):

`validateScript`, can provide a more flexible solution and would work well if you needed additional parameter validation. This also allows you to get a list of the valid parameters outside of the `foo` function, with the creation of the `get-validTypes` function.

```
Function Foo {
    Param (
        [validateScript({test-validTypes $_})]
        [String]$Type = 'Startup'
    )

    get-validTypes
}

function get-validTypes {

    $powerOptions = @('Startup', 'Shutdown', 'LogOn', 'LogOff')
    Write-Output $powerOptions

}

function test-validTypes {
[cmdletbinding()]
param ($typeInput)

    $validTypes = get-validTypes
    if ($validTypes.contains($typeInput)){
        return $true
    } else {
        Write-Error "Invalid Type Paramater, Must be on of the following: $powerOptions"
    }

}
```

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but this does seem like an unnecessarily cumbersome workaround (where none is needed) that makes the code less readable.

Comment: @mklement0 I agree, but don't plan on removing the answer because it is a valid approach if additional validation is needed.

Comment: @mklement0, what "unrelated benefits" does this approach provide that are not done by `ValidateSet()`?

Comment: @lit, I was referring to the additional validation that a script-block-based approach can provide that Eric mentioned.