# How does ValidateSet stop a variable being changed to a non-set value?

Tags: powershell

I've just noticed that if you are using `ValidateSet` for a parameter variable in a function you cannot within that function change the parameter variable to a value that is not in the set.

Here is a simple example to demonstrate:

```
Function Test {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param(
        [ValidateSet(1,2,3)]
        [int]$Number
    )

    $Number = 4
}

Test 3
```

Returns:

> The variable cannot be validated because the value 4 is not a valid value for the Number variable.

I've used `Get-Member` to explore `$Number` and I can't see any indication of how (or why) it restricts the variable like this. I assume it's some sort of custom object or strong typing but the variable looks to be a `System.Int32`. Does anyone know how/why this happens?

This isn't unique to `Int` variables, this is just a simple example. I have found the same true for a String Array parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discovered from this related question: [Find the values in ValidateSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42697072/find-the-values-in-validateset) that if I do the following inside my function:

```
(Get-Variable 'Number').Attributes.ValidValues
```

this lists the defined `ValidateSet` values. I therefore assume setting this attribute is how `ValidateSet` works, with the side effect being that it is then in effect throughout the life of the variable.

Comment: If there is a PowerShell wiki somewhere, I would strongly urge you to place this information therein!

Comment: FWIW, the same goes for "strong" type constraints on assignment, compare `[bool]$a = $true;(variable a).Attributes` and `$b = $true;(variable b).Attributes`