# Testing for ValidateSet() [System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute]

Tags: powershell

The answer from @mklement0 is very helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42699260/447901

I wanted to write a script that will produce all Github configuration settings. The PowerShellForGitHub module function Get-GitHubConfiguration only reports one at a time and you must already know the name of the setting. The settings supported vary across versions. This code gets the setting names based on the ValidateSet() for the $Name parameter and produces them all.

The question is... Is it important to test that the Attribute is of type [System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute]? What other type might it be?

Both of the `$Names =` lines produce the same array.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
#$Names = (Get-Command -Name 'Get-GitHubConfiguration').Parameters.Name.Attributes.ValidValues
$Names = ((Get-Command -Name 'Get-GitHubConfiguration').Parameters.Name.Attributes |
    Where-Object { $_ -is [System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute] }).ValidValues

foreach ($Name in $Names) {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name = $Name
        Value = Get-GitHubConfiguration -Name $Name
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using [this `Get-GitHubConfiguration`  implementation](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerShellForGitHub/blob/5e1a4b312996ac894e01fa13c9677b1f302becfb/GitHubConfiguration.ps1#L289), it is the `-Name` parameter you're interested in, and the following command extracts the values defined for its [`[ValidateSet]`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute) attribute:

```bash
$names = 
  (Get-Command Get-GitHubConfiguration).
    Parameters['Name'].
    Attributes.Where({ $_ -is [ValidateSet] }).
    ValidValues
```

`$names` then contains an array of strings (`@('ApiHostName', 'ApplicationInsightsKey', ...)`)

---

PowerShell offers several attributes for validating arguments passed to parameters, but only the following allow discovery of a discrete set or a range of permissible values:

- [`[ValidateSet]`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute), both with *statically* enumerated values, as in the case at hand, and - in PowerShell (Core) 7+ only - via a helper class that implements the [`IValidateSetValuesGenerator`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.IValidateSetValuesGenerator) interface for *dynamic* generation of the permissible values.
- [`[ValidateRange]`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ValidateRangeAttribute) for limiting arguments to a range of values, defined via inclusive endpoints.

Comment: @lit, it is _technically possible_ to combine them, but it _doesn't make sense_, given that _both_ constraints are enforced: if the `[ValidateSet]` values are a  _subset_ of the  values in the `[ValidateRange]` range, the latter has no effect. If the `[ValidateSet]` comprises values that are _outside_ the range specified `[ValidateRange]`, they can never be passed.